# How to avoid duplicate results in grouped SOLR Search

Tags: solr, duplicates

I have a SOLR query

```
group.field=USER_TYPE&group.limit=3&group.format=grouped
```

So, this perfectly groups based on the user type. But, the results inside the groups contains a duplicate. That is, each user has a unique user_id and a user_group. Each user can have multiple user_group. So, the result contains duplicate users with different user_groups and same user_id. I wanted the grouped results should not contain a duplicate user_id value.

```
{"groupValue":"A","doclist":{"numFound":849956,"start":0,"maxScore":9.992027,\
    "docs":[
        {"user_group":"GPA","user_id":"4443510",.....},
        {"user_group":"GPB","user_id":"4443510",.....},
        {"user_group":"GPC","user_id":"4443510",.....},
        ....
        ]
```

Can anyone please help to avoid duplicates in this case.

**EDIT:**
I am expecting the result could be

```
{"groupValue":"A","doclist":{"numFound":849956,"start":0,"maxScore":9.992027,       
    "docs":[
        {"groupValue":"4443510"
            "docs":[            
                {"user_group":"GPA","user_id":"4443510",.....},
                {"user_group":"GPB","user_id":"4443510",.....},
                {"user_group":"GPC","user_id":"4443510",.....},
                ....
                ]
        ....
        ]
```

Comment: I don't think that would be possible. You would want the user_id to be present in one of the groups, right? But how would Solr know which one. I believe this would have to be done on the client?

Comment: I updated the expected result in the question. Is there anything I could to at RequestHandler in SolrConfig.xml?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to do grouping within a group.

But on the other hand, I think you could solve this issue by modifying the way you are indexing.

Now, you have multiple documents for each user_id:

```
 "docs":[            
                {"user_group":"GPA","user_id":"4443510",.....},
                {"user_group":"GPB","user_id":"4443510",.....},
                {"user_group":"GPC","user_id":"4443510",.....},
                ....
                ]
```

You can modify it as follows to solve the issue:

```
 "docs":[            
                {"user_group":["GPA","GPB","GPC"],"user_id":"4443510",.....},
                {"user_group":["GPB"],"user_id":"4443511",.....},
                {"user_group":["GPA","GPC"],"user_id":"4443512",.....},
                ....
                ]
```

I mean you can modify the **user_group** to be **mutivalued**, so that you have **only one document per user**.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers. But, I cant change the indexing since it being used by other systems also. So the impact will be high.